# What is the best practice implementation of a Javascript download button?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I have an html interface to my server. On the interface is a button. When a user clicks the button, they download a file located on the server.

My current implementation appends an iframe to the html document, after the user presses the button. The iframe has it's url parameter set to the uri of the file on the server, and a display parameter of "none". It is appended to the body of the document.

My question is, what is the best practice for achieving a result like this? i.e. How should the button handler manage the download?

Comment: I think it's not very likely that the iframe has anything to do with the problem. Other than your character encoding issues I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.  What exactly do you mean by "safe" here?

Comment: The question was more about the best practice for implementation of such a download button, rather than the problems I am experiencing. I have edited the question to this affect.

Comment: Why go with this complex way? You could do this with some PHP and set headers to force the browser to download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *Best Practice* is to use a form with your buttons.  E.g:

```
<form method="get" action="/file-to-download.zip">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
  </div>
</form>
```

If you *really* need it to be targeted at an IFRAME (which seems unnecessary as aroth explained - and you can always set the Content-Disposition response header for recognised types), you can put `target="myIFrame"` in your form tag (myIFrame being the name of your hidden IFRAME).

In fact, the [Content-Disposition response header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) is the *Best Practice* for ensuring the file is downloaded rather than opened.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do something like:

`window.location.href = <download URL>;`?

That should work in any browser, and it shouldn't even take the user off your web page (from the perspective of what is displayed in the browser), unless your downloadable content is being served with a mime-type that the browser will try to render itself (like `image/png`, for example).

Comment: in Chrome Html 5 video I am getting a Network Error with this approach, any ideas on how to get around this?